# VSCode Prisma extension not formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, prisma

Prisma extension suddenly stopped formatting my schema.prisma with the proper indention. Below is the language server output after save.

```
[Trace - 4:05:26 AM] Sending request 'textDocument/formatting - (247)'.
Params: {
    "textDocument": {
        "uri": "mypath/schema.prisma"
    },
    "options": {
        "tabSize": 2,
        "insertSpaces": true
    }
}


[Trace - 4:05:26 AM] Received notification 'window/logMessage'.
Params: {
    "type": 4,
    "message": "running format() from prisma-fmt"
}


running format() from prisma-fmt
[Trace - 4:05:26 AM] Received response 'textDocument/formatting - (247)' in 3ms.
Result: [
    {
        "range": {
            "start": {
                "line": 0,
                "character": 0
            },
            "end": {
                "line": 67,
                "character": 9007199254740991
            }
        },
        "newText": "generator client {\n  provider = \"prisma-client-js\"\n}\n\ndatasource db {\n  provider = \"sqlite\"\n  url      = env(\"DATABASE_URL\")\n}\n\nmodel Example {\n  id String @id @default(cuid())\n}\n\n// Necessary for Next auth\nmodel Account {\n  id                String  @id @default(cuid())\n  userId            String\n  type              String\n  provider          String\n  providerAccountId String\n  refresh_token     String? //@db.Text\n  access_token      String? //@db.Text\n  expires_at        Int?\n  token_type        String?\n  scope             String?\n  id_token          String? //@db.Text\n  session_state     String?\n  user              User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)\n\n  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])\n}\n\nmodel Session {\n  id           String   @id @default(cuid())\n  sessionToken String   @unique\n  userId       String\n  expires      DateTime\n  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)\n}\n\nmodel User {\n  id            String    @id @default(cuid())\n  name          String?\n  email         String?   @unique\n  emailVerified DateTime?\n  image         String?\n  accounts      Account[]\n  sessions      Session[]\n  placeId       String?\n}\n\nmodel VerificationToken {\n  identifier String\n  token      String   @unique\n  expires    DateTime\n\n  @@unique([identifier, token])\n}\n\n// End of Next Auth\n"
    }
]


[Trace - 4:05:26 AM] Sending notification 'textDocument/didSave'.
Params: {
    "textDocument": {
        "uri": "mypath/schema.prisma"
    }
}
```

It should look like this
[image]

But it looks like this
[image]

I have Prettier installed and I added the following snippet my settings.json no change.

```
"[prisma]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Prisma.prisma"
},
```

I also have

```
"editor.formatOnSave": true
```

I'm using v4.3.1 of the Prisma Extension and v1.71.0 of VSCode

I've tried changing the extension version which produced no change.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier-plugin-prisma helped me resolve formatting issue

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error, then I found this issue on GitHub with the following code, and it worked:

```
"[prisma]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Prisma.prisma"
},
```

Comment: OP mentioned that this is not the solution

Answer (score 2):

1. Install **prisma Insider** in *VS Code*
2. Add these lines in *Settings.josn*

```
  "[prisma]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Prisma.prisma-insider"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
```

Now formatting will work.

Answer (score 1):

Go to VS Code

1 : `Ctrl + Shift + P` => Palette will be opened

2 : Search Settings.json

3 : Click `Preferences:Open User Settings (JSON)`

4 : Paste the following code inside the curly brace`,"editor.formatOnSave": true`

[Paste Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCUOF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had `editor.formatOnSaveMode` set to `modificationsIfAvailable` which was preventing the format. So I set my settings like below and it worked for me:

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modificationsIfAvailable",
"[prisma]": {
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file",
},
```

Above config will make sure:

- Format on save is enabled for all files
- format only happens to modifications you did on the file and not all the time
- But for prisma schema modification happens on whole file everytime
- As of Prisma extension `v5.6.0`, I did not need to specify any default formatter as I think its already set to `Prisma.prisma` and any other bugs preventing formatting are also fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `settings.json` file and formatting should work:

```
"[prisma]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "Prisma.prisma"
}
```